# Start up code in embedded c

Tags: embedded, startup, clock

How can clock initialisation in a microcontroller be done using start up code?
A general approach is enough.

Comment: It depends. This question can not be answered in a meaningful way. You need to specify more.

Comment: You're question is unclear. Are you talking about the hardware clock? Normally, the HW clock will have some kind of a reset command. You would send this to the HW clock.

Answer (score 4):

Read the datasheet of the device, do what it says.